# Why would gdb ignore Control C

Tags: gdb

Centos7, gdb 'GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.1-80.el7'.

Here's what I do:

- I use gdb -p to attach to a process.
- Set a breakpoint
- 'c'

Now, I realize that I should have set two breakpoints. OK, I hit 'Control-C'. GDB ignores me, it does not come back out to command line.

Do I have to arrange for some signal to arrive at the process I'm debugging, instead?

Comment: Perhaps this might be useful :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857300/gdb-ctrlc-doesnt-interrupt-process-as-it-usually-does-but-rather-terminates-t